Struggling to conditionally reset value of variable to zero
My code doesn't work because the value of the variable profit is derived by division using the variable buy_price which is currently set to 0 before profit is returned.
buy_price = 0

def tradeStrategy(row):
    global buy_price

    #entry conditions
    if buy_price==0 and row['ema200'] < row['ema50']:
        buy_price = row['close']
        
    #exit conditions
    if buy_price > 0 and row['ADX_14']<20 or (row['ADX_14']>20 and row['DMP_14']<row['DMN_14']) or row['ema200'] > row['ema50'] :
        sell_price = row['close']
        profit = 1000*((sell_price-buy_price)/buy_price)
        buy_price = 0
        return profit

btc_1m_2023['tradeStrategy'] = btc_1m_2023.apply(tradeStrategy, axis=1)

How can I set buy_price to zero ONLY if my exit conditions are met and AFTER profit is returned?

The expected behavior is unclear. You must provide a [mre], the matching expected output, and a description of the logic to clearly demonstrate what you're trying to achieve.

Instead of using the apply function you should iterate through each row and call tradeStrategy
buy_price = 0

def tradeStrategy(row):
    global buy_price

    # entry conditions
    if buy_price == 0 and row['ema200'] < row['ema50']:
        buy_price = row['close']
        
    # exit conditions
    if buy_price > 0 and (row['ADX_14'] < 20 or (row['ADX_14'] > 20 and row['DMP_14'] < row['DMN_14']) or row['ema200'] > row['ema50']):
        sell_price = row['close']
        profit = 1000 * ((sell_price - buy_price) / buy_price)
        temp_buy_price = buy_price  # Store buy_price temporarily
        buy_price = 0  # Reset buy_price after profit calculation
        return profit, temp_buy_price  # Return profit and buy_price

    return None, None  # Return None if exit conditions are not met

profits = []
temp_buy_prices = []

for index, row in btc_1m_2023.iterrows():
    profit, temp_buy_price = tradeStrategy(row)
    if profit is not None:
        profits.append(profit)
        temp_buy_prices.append(temp_buy_price)

btc_1m_2023['tradeStrategyProfit'] = profits
btc_1m_2023['tempBuyPrice'] = temp_buy_prices

